# VSFTPD 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/logs

Tags: linux, vsftpd, yocto, vsftp

I am getting error `500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/logs` while using file zila client to access this directory. My linux kernel version is "4.9.11". I have created a user called `log_user` which corresponds to `/logs` directory. This custom user I have created this by using my custom yocto layer which corresponds to "rocko" version. Below is my `vsftpd.conf` file

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
local_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_config/
```

Below is my `/etc/vsftpd/user_config/log_user` file

```
local_root=/logs
write_enable=YES
```

Here is the output of `ls` in the root directory for `.` and `..`

```
$ ls -als / 
4 drwxrwx--- 23 root netdev  4096 Jan  1  1970 .
4 drwxrwx--- 23 root netdev  4096 Jan  1  1970 ..
```

The `/logs` directory has 755 permissions. I have found one hack that is if I manually give the below command in the root directory ftp works like magic !

```
cd /
chmod 755 .
```

Is there any other way or some other configuration changes I can do to achieve ftp connection without touching the file permissions in the root directory? As I need to protect my file systems.

Comment: `chmod 754 /` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Philippos actually I don't want to touch the file permissions of / .

Comment: @Philippos also chmod 754 is not working